# Difference between server and client

Tags: server, client

What is the difference between server and client? What difference does it make for some software installations?

For example, I've checked on how to download and install cvs and one of the user asked about server or client.

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090318141953AAVtaXI
Google is your friend.  If you're downloading something for personal use, you probably want "client".

Comment: interesting that this question got a Gold badge for 'famous question' yet (currently at least) it has a -1 score.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck being famous and good are two completely orthogonal things. This is not a good question, but a lot of people searched about it.

Comment: So, why would someone downvote if it is helping a lot of people. If scientists neglect explaining trivial topics to lay people or reaching out to them thinking it is too simple to be explained and that they better learn themselves somehow, then expect budget cuts for science as too many a people would think it is something not necessary why waste money on that. It is a kind of elitism if you think that topics which are simple but are in popular demand don't deserve attention on the forum.

Comment: And @felix Gagnon -Gerner no they are not the same, the question I asked is basic concept compared to the question you are comparing it to.

Comment: Hey there @AvinashreddyPakala! Thanks for getting back to me after such a long time! I believe you have a slight misunderstanding of what a downvote represents. Contrary to popular belief, it does not mean that you are a bad person, or that you should be ashamed. It's really just a *signal*, that says to other users, that a question is (or not) **on-topic, properly researched, or otherwise relevant**. This question, while important for learning, is really not researched. That's what downvotes express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A server is a program, or machine, that waits for incoming requests.

A client is a program, or machine, that sends requests to servers.

Wikipedia: [Server (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_%28computing%29), [Client (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_%28computing%29)

For cvs; Are you setting up your own project, in which case you will need to set up the cvs server as well as a client to connect to said server.  Or are you connecting to an existing project, in which case you need the client.

Answer (score 1):

In simplest form, a server is a connection point for several clients, that will handle their requests.

A client is software that (usually) connects to the server to perform actions.  The client provide a user interface that allows users to carry out actions.  It forwards these requests to the server, which carries out the action and returns a response.

In CVS, the server is where the central data repository is held, and client is what you use to access the said repository.

Answer (score 1):

Server: A computer on the network that shares resources for others to use is called a server computer.
Client: A computer on the network that accesses resources that are shared by computers is known as a client computer.

Answer (score 0):

Server is machine that fullfill the request sent by clients.

Client is a machine that sends request  to server