# How to call Jquery parameter from C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I am creating a dynamic button while listing the data in the function below. When the button is clicked, I want the ID to go as a crypto string, but I could not get the item value.

```
  function ProductListToDisplay(data) {
        var content = "";

        $(data).each(function (indx, item) {
           content += '<tr>';
           content += '<a class="mr-2" href="/CPY/CpyDoc_Dokumanlar/Delete?id=@Uri.EscapeDataString(CryptoProvider.Encrypt(item.id.ToString()))"></a> </span></td>';
           content += '</tr>';
    
       });
    }
```

Comment: At the time when button is renders add a javascript function to be called and
Pass the Id as a parameter to the function

Comment: What error are you getting on your browser console while performing this action? Can you try this way: `<a class="mr-2" href="/CPY/CpyDoc_Dokumanlar/Delete?id=@Uri.EscapeDataString(CryptoProvider.Encrypt(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item.id))))"></a>`

Comment: I tried it didn't work I get the **"The name 'item' does not exist in the current context"** error @RahulSharma

Comment: @MeralTd Your `item` is a JS variable. Try removing `ToString` from it. You basically need to access your `js` variable inside the c# method?

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes I need to access js variable inside c# method

Comment: @MeralTd Well, the opposite is definitely possible but according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900614/use-javascript-variable-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-syntax and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317182/how-to-pass-a-value-to-razor-variable-from-javascript-variable, you can not use Javascript variables in C#, because javascript code is available only after C# / Razor is rendered